# Error with getting user data in azureAD graph

Tags: model-view-controller, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@using Microsoft.Graph
@using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web
@using Azure.Identity;
@using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;

@inject GraphServiceClient GraphServiceClient
@inject ITokenAcquisition TokenAcquisition
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
@inject IOptionsMonitor<AzureADOptions> AzureADOptions

@{
    var displayName = "Default UserName";

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        // Values from app registration
        var clientId = "hidden";
        var tenantId = "hidden";
        var clientSecret = "hidden";

        // using Azure.Identity;
        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
                };

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        var user = await graphClient.Me
    .GetAsync();
    }
}

<ul class="navbar-auth">
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li class="navbar-auth-text">
            <a class="navbar-auth-text" asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="Index">@displayName</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-auth-text">
            <form id="logoutForm" method="post" asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="/">
                <button type="submit" class="navbar-auth-text">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="navbar-auth-text">
            <a class="navbar-auth-text" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Signin">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

specifically the following code:

```
var user = await graphClient.Me
    .GetAsync();
```

is having an error where I cant get the user data. and is throwing this error.

```
Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendAsync[ModelType](RequestInformation requestInfo, ParsableFactory`1 factory, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Me.MeRequestBuilder.GetAsync(Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Shared__LoginPartial.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Users\liam lundberg\source\repos\FoodSpace\FoodSpace\Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml:line 39
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.RenderPartialViewAsync(TextWriter writer, Object model, IView view)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.PartialTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, Int32 i, Int32 count)
   at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Shared__Layout.ExecuteAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultFilters>g__Awaited|28_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

im expecting to get the user data which i plan to get the displayname from.

it would be greatful if there is someone experienced that can help. im logging in fine without that specific line of code. but when im using it I get the error

Comment: You are connecting to the Graph API as a daemon or background service with application permissions. In that case await graphClient.Me.GetAsync(); will not work, because you are not signed as a user.

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with *@user2250152*, you cannot get signed-in user details using **client credentials** flow as it uses Application permissions.

When I ran similar code as you to get signed-in user display name using client credentials flow, I got **same error** like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appID";
var tenantId = "tenantID";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine(result.DisplayName);
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, you need to make use of **interactive flows**
> where user will sign in like authorization code flow or interactive
> flow etc...

In my case, I used **interactive flow** by running below code and got signed-in user's **display name** successfully in response like this:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

var clientId = "appID";
var tenantId = "tenantID";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,

    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine(result.DisplayName);
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=csharp#interactive-provider)